# change src of img element by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change src of element img?. I want to change this attribute to other, when cite has only one class : user. How to do it? In this case there should change src in img '//img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif' to another. Source of img '//somethingelse.gif' should remain the same.

```
<ol id='bc_0_4TB'>
        <li id='bc_0_2B' class='comment' kind='b'>
            <div class='avatar-image-container'>
                <img src='//img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif'></img>
            </div>
            <div id='c5653317936849872669' class='comment-block'>
                <div id='bc_0_2M' class='comment-header' kind='m'>
                    <cite class='user'>Anonymous</cite>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id='bc_0_3B' class='comment' kind='b'>
            <div class='avatar-image-container'>
                <img src='//somethingelse.gif'></img>
            </div>
            <div id='c5653317936849872670' class='comment-block'>
                <div id='bc_0_2M' class='comment-header' kind='m'>
                    <cite class='user blog-author'>Author</cite>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>    
    </ol>
```

Comment: $('img').attr('src', src);

Comment: but i need add condition when cite has only one class : user

Comment: add a condition then: `if(!$('.cite').hasClass(''));`
I am hoping you know which class will be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to change this attribute to other, when cite has only one class
>   : user

You can use:

```
$('cite[class="user"]').closest('li').find('img').attr('src','newSrc');
```

Comment: That is an invalid attribute selector for jquery >= 1.8ish

Comment: @NickLarsen What do you mean exactly?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/, valid attribute selectors must quote the value portion of the atrribute.

Comment: @NickLarsen `Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks.` Thx but that's a [valid identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)  Anyway, i quoted it for readability :)

Answer (score 0):

To change the `src` attribute using jquery, just set it using the `.attr()` function.  http://api.jquery.com/attr/

For the logic to change it only when you want to change it.  Please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: i dont know how to work with childrens and siblings , because i want to change src only of img, where cite has only class called user